# Relationship between euclidean distance and covariance matrix distances

Tags: covariance-matrix, metric, inequality

Consider three random vectors $x, y, z$ taking values in $\mathbb R^n$. They have mean zero, e.g., $E(x_i)=0$, and covariance matrix $\Omega_x$, $\Omega_y$, $\Omega_z$. Assume that the following relationship holds:

$$
E||x-y||^2 \le E||x-z||^2
$$

where $||.||$ is the Euclidean norm in $\mathbb R^n$.

Is it possible to establish a similar ordering between covariance matrix distances? By this I mean that, for *some* matrix norm $||.||_*$ (e.g., Frobenius, operator, nuclear, L1, etc.), the following holds:

$$
 ||\Omega_x - \Omega_y||_*^2 \le  ||\Omega_x- \Omega_z||^2_*
$$

Intuitively, it seems it should.

Comment: I do not understand what you are asking because the covariance matrices are not random variables.  What, then, could possibly be the meaning of taking expectations of norms of their differences?

Comment: Sorry, that was a typo. Corrected.

Comment: Thank you.  But could you explain why you think this might be generally true? Consider, for instance, the case where $x$ and $z$ are independent but have the same covariance matrix.  That makes the right hand side of your conclusion zero in any norm, which would imply you think $y$ necessarily has the same covariance matrix as $x$ whenever your first expectation inequality holds.  Why should that be the case?

Comment: I am afraid you are right. You provided a counterexample, and my intuition is wrong. Thanks.